# Annotation @OrderBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to automatically order the results of a report by the ManyToMany annotation `@OrderBy`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="soundtrack", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="soundtrack_artist")
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC", "surname" = "ASC"})
 **/
private $artists;
```

but it gives me this error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@OrderBy" in property
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Soundtrack::$artists was never imported.
Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

I tried to add also:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\OrderBy;
```

But the error remains!
I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: dont forget to clear the cache!

Comment: Thank you guys!
I lose myself in a glass of water at times!

Comment: Guys, it does not work!
Continue to sort them by id: `public function getArtistsAction()
    {
        $artists = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BasiSuMisuraUserBundle:Artist')->findAll();
        foreach($artists as $a) {
            var_dump($a->getId());
        }
        die;
        return array('artists' => $artists);
    }` returns:
int (1)
int (2)
...  I deleted the cache but does not seem to work.

Comment: Instead of `var_dump($a->getId());` try `Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($a)` and look at your `name` variable then `surname`. Maybe they are ordered, but it's hard to tell when you print the `id`

Comment: I solved the same issue removing the spaces, where you have @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"}) I changed to @ORM\OrderBy({"name"="ASC"}) removing the space between the words, It solved for me.

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if you found the answer, but this worked for me:

> @ORM\OrderBy

Answer (score 14):

If you include this namespace:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

This annotation will work:

```
@ORM\OrderBy({"date" = "ASC"})
```

The first key should be a mapped attribute of your class. The order should be ASC or DESC.

Please refer to Doctrine official documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

Answer (score 3):

`@ORM\OrderBy` resolve all problem, in symfony annotation its important inserting the scope of a method.